# Display Swing application window through a webpage

Tags: java, swing

There is a Swing GUI application made using Java that is open sourced, but I need to integrate it into a website rather than having people download the application. Is there a way to display the application window through a webpage? Sort of like run the application into the background and then display the window on the webpage. Any ideas would be super helpful.

Comment: *"Is there a way to display the application window through a webpage?"* No. There **used** to be applets, but those were deprecated and removed from browsers and the API. *"Any ideas would be super helpful."* Convert the app. to Javascript.

Comment: Tip: https://Vaadin.com/